# Приложение крашится

Tags: python, kivy

Логи, что взял из CatLog:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/m/8/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/home/m/8/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivymd/uix/filemanager.py", line 119, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
Python for android ended.
```

Причем модуль PIL я не использую, только отображаю изображения из памяти

Comment: KivyMD использует - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD#dependencies

Comment: Я пробовал добавлять Pillow/pillow/PIL/pil, но тогда apkшник не собирался